# Learning Javascript / JQuery + Parsing a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

I am new to Javascript / JQuery...and right now all I am trying to do (to learn) is to make a page that extracts information from a google calendar (public) and displays the events along with start date + time plus end date and time. So far I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var baseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/qq3hkhn3dj8gt05q539smmk2go@group.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyB66zMow3CSeTdM1m_X_0Wj1JxCtSTd8kU&alt=json&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result.items[0].created);
        }         
    });
});
</script>
```

In my console, the output I see is:

```
2012-01-07T23:46:15.000Z
```

Now, what I want to do is, parse this date and time into a pretty looking string, something like "January 1, 2012" and same for the time. How should I proceed? I do not want to step outside JS / JQuery / AJAX.

Also, I would appreciate comments / feedback on my code so far - does this seem a normal / good way to do it, or should I approach it differently?

Thanks, let me know please!

Comment: Just googling date formats in javascript. https://www.google.com/search?ix=hcb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+format+date If you want your code reviewed try - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, but the javascript date object does not include TIME does it? How do I extract that from there?

Comment: the very first link shows you how to extract time under the h1 heading `get the javascript time`

Comment: Thanks, but I dont see the format I specified? And how exactly would I use that function?

Comment: For the love of Pete.. did you even bother reading the article or trying it. `var foo = new Date('yourstring'); alert(foo.getHours());`

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
var date = new Date(result.items[0].created);
date.toLocaleString();
```

The format of `toLocaleString()` is different by browser. If you want precise control over the format, try using a library such as [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/), [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/), or the `formatDate` function provided by [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate).

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse date string and convert it to date. This date library in Javascript contains some useful functions for the conversion you need.

http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/source.html

I think you can use `getDateFromFormat` function in this.